# If Durmstrang and Beauxbatons were hidden from common knowledge, how did people from other schools go to them for the Triwizard tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

So in GoF, they state that Beauxbatons and Durmstrang are hidden from view and don't have their locations public.

> “Durmstrang’s another wizarding school?” said Harry
>
> “Yes,” said Hermione sniffily, “and it’s got a horrible reputation.
>
> According to *An Appraisal of Magical Education in Europe*, it puts a
>   lot of emphasis on the Dark Arts.”
>
> “I think I’ve heard of it,” said Ron vaguely. “Where is it? What
>   country?”
>
> “Well, nobody knows, do they?” said Hermione, raising her
>   eyebrows.
>
> “Er — why not?” said Harry.
>
> “There’s traditionally been a lot of rivalry between all the magic
>   schools. Durmstrang and Beauxbatons like to conceal their whereabouts
>   so nobody can steal their secrets,” said Hermione matter-offactly.

So how do students get to the other school for the Triwizard tournament?

Comment: Surely, that means from the Muggles... They each knew how to get to Hogwarts after all...

Comment: @Skooba Karkaroff makes a comment about keeping and protecting their school's secrets.  Although I don't think he is talking about their location.

Comment: @Skooba look above....

Comment: Just because you do not know where something is, does not mean you do not know how to get there,

Comment: Couldn't we assume that they distribute portkeys to the rival schools when it comes time to arrive for the Triwizard tournament?

Comment: No, because they didn't use portkeys to get here, ey?

Comment: If the locations are secret, one could infer that the headmaster/headmistress is a secret keeper for their whereabouts.  The tri-wizard tournament is about uniting the wizarding community, so the trust of giving that secret to another headmaster seems in line with doing just that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hogwarts was just as concealed:

> “But Hogwarts is hidden,” said Hermione, in surprise. “Everyone knows
> that . . . well, everyone who’s read *Hogwarts, A History*, anyway.”
>
> “Just you, then,” said Ron. “So go on — how d’you hide a place like
> Hogwarts?”
>
> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a Muggle looks at it, all they
> see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying
> danger, do not enter, unsafe.”
>
> “So Durmstrang’ll just look like a ruin to an outsider too?”
>
> “Maybe,”
> said Hermione, shrugging, “or it might have Muggle-repelling charms on
> it, like the World Cup stadium. And to keep foreign wizards from
> finding it, they’ll have made it Unplottable —”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Nonetheless, the delegations from the foreign schools had no trouble finding it. One presumes that Dumbledore could make the location available to the students from Beaxbatons and Durmstrang, if need be. He certainly seems to be able to remove the protective spells around Hogwarts:

> As they flew over the dark, twisting lane down which they had walked
> earlier, Harry heard, over the whistling of the night air in his ears,
> Dumbledore muttering in some strange language again. He thought he
> understood why as he felt his broom shudder when they flew over the
> boundary wall into the grounds: Dumbledore was undoing the
> enchantments he himself had set around the castle so they could enter
> at speed.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

A similar situation probably holds with Durmstrang and Beauxbatons: they can simply alter or remove their spells to allow in foreign students. In particular, given that the delegations only arrive on a single day, they would only need to lift their protective enchantments for a very short period.

Comment: Better than a short window being fully unprotected, perhaps they use two factor authentication.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard It took place in the 90's, so I'm honestly surprised they even used _one_ factor auth. :)

Comment: @Wildcard : based on how wizards think, it seems much more likely they just use some barely sentient magical animal or enchanted object to guard it, which can be easily circumvented by answering a riddle or by finding a very obvious weak point.

Answer (score 7):

## Durmstrang’s visitors agree to be charmed to forget the way to it.

Hosting people from other schools wouldn’t be a problem for keeping where Durmstrang is a secret. Visitors to Durmstrang have to agree to have memory charms used on them so they forget how they got there and its location remains secret. Visitors coming for the Triwizard Tournament would presumably also be required to agree to have memory charms used on them.

> Although believed to be situated in the far north of Europe, Durmstrang is one of the most secretive of all schools about its whereabouts, so nobody can be quite certain. Visitors, who must comply with memory charms to erase their knowledge of how they got there, speak of vast, sprawling grounds with many stunning views, not least of the great, dark, spectral ship that is moored on a mountain lake behind the school, from which students dive in summertime. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Durmstrang Institute (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute)*</sup></sub>

It’s not mentioned how Beauxbatons controls what knowledge Triwizard Tournament visitors leave with, but this at least gives an idea what one of the participating schools handles this.

Comment: A very good find. You have my +1

Answer (score 6):

There are, according to Hermione, two layers of charms applied to the schools; Muggle-repelling charms and unplottability. The Muggle-repelling charms make the schools invisible to muggles, but not witches and wizards. The unplottability makes the school invisible to witches and wizards and prevents the school from showing up on maps.

Since students (and teachers) regularly leave Hogwarts and come back again, there must be some sort of loophole that allows **those with the permission of the school's management** to come and go without falling foul of the unplottability. It can be assumed that the Ministry of Magic would coordinate permission being given to delegates of foreign schools to see through the illusions and to come to the schools in the event of an international tournament.

Their locations may be a general sort of secret, but it beggars belief that after a thousand years, everyone in the wizarding world *who needs to know where these schools are*, doesn't actually know exactly where they are.

Comment: What's your source that unplottable locations are also invisible?

Comment: @orangedog - Grimmauld Place, although that has a bunch of other charms on it as well.

Comment: @Valorum Grimmauld Place was invisible because of the Fidelius Charm, wasn't it? Hence why Harry could see it after the secret was shared with him.

Comment: @mikekellogg - Good question, can't remember

Comment: From the quote in another answer, it sounds like Hermione is speculating. I'll freely admit that her speculations are likely to be correct, but the point needs to be made.